# overgeneralized curried fns

Tags: ocaml, monomorphism

```
module MapHelpers (Ord : Map.OrderedType) = struct
  include Map.Make (Ord)
  let add_all a b = fold add a b
end
```

works but the seemingly equivalent

```
module MapHelpers (Ord : Map.OrderedType) = struct
  include Map.Make (Ord)
  let add_all = fold add
end
```

fails to compile with

```
File "Foo.ml", line 2, characters 18-104:
Error: The type of this module,
       functor (Ord : Map.OrderedType) ->
         sig
           ...
           val add_all : '_a t -> '_a t -> '_a t
         end,
       contains type variables that cannot be generalized
Command exited with code 2.
```

and adding an explicit type annotation

```
: 'a . 'a t -> 'a t -> 'a t
```

causes compilation to fail earlier with

```
Error: This definition has type 'a t -> 'a t -> 'a t
       which is less general than 'a0. 'a0 t -> 'a0 t -> 'a0 t
```

Why does adding the explicit formals `a b` change the way these two modules are typed?

Comment: You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242677/what-is-the-difference-between-a-and-l . Caml used to implement “value restriction” and now implements “relaxed value restriction”, I think: http://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~garrigue/papers/morepoly-long.pdf

Comment: @PascalCuoq, I see the "or when defining polymorphic functions that are not syntactically functions"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a consequence of the value restriction, as described in the following FAQ item:

[A function obtained through partial application is not polymorphic enough](http://caml.inria.fr/resources/doc/faq/core.en.html#eta-expansion)

> The more common case to get a ``not polymorphic enough'' definition is when defining a function via partial application of a general polymorphic function. In Caml polymorphism is introduced only through the “let” construct, and results from application are weakly polymorph; hence the function resulting from the application is not polymorph. In this case, you recover a fully polymorphic definition by clearly exhibiting the functionality to the type-checker : define the function with an explicit functional abstraction, that is, add a function construct or an extra parameter (this rewriting is known as eta-expansion):
>
> ```
> # let map_id = List.map (function x -> x) (* Result is weakly polymorphic *)
> val map_id : '_a list -> '_a list = <fun>
> # map_id [1;2]
> - : int list = [1;2]
> # map_id (* No longer polymorphic *)
> - : int list -> int list = <fun>
> # let map_id' l = List.map (function x -> x) l
> val map_id' : 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
> # map_id' [1;2]
> - : int list = [1;2]
> # map_id' (* Still fully polymorphic *)
> - : 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
> ```
>
> The two definitions are semantically equivalent, and the new one can be assigned a polymorphic type scheme, since it is no more a function application.

See also [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4244620/298143) about what the `_` in `'_a` indicates -- weak, non-polymorphic type variables.