# What's the difference between these two functions?

Tags: ocaml

I have two functions:

```
let rev_flatten l = 
  List.fold_left (fun acc x -> List.fold_left (fun acc y -> y::acc) acc x) [] l
```

The type is `val rev_flatten : 'a list list -> 'a list = <fun>`

and

```
let rev_flatten = 
  List.fold_left (fun acc x -> List.fold_left (fun acc y -> y::acc) acc x) []
```

The type is `val rev_flatten : '_a list list -> '_a list = <fun>`

---

I think it is the same functions, at least the same functionality, but why they have two different types? Why the second has the element type of `_a`? What is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A type variable with underscore as a prefix tells us that the variable is *weakly polymorphic*. A weakly polymorphic variable can be used only with one type, however a compiler can't deduce the exact type, so the type variable is mark with underscore.

When you provide an argument for the first time, a variable will no longer be polymorphic and will be able to accept arguments of a single type only.

Usually, a function is not generalized, but marked as weakly polymorphic if it *might* contain mutable state. In your example this is probably the case, because type system doesn't know if `List.fold_left` is pure or impure function.

**Edit:**
Why avoiding partial application (*eta expansion*) allows function (even impure) to be polymorphic?

Let's define a function that have an internal counter that is incremented and printed out every time the function is called. Among this, it takes a function as the argument and applies it after increasing the counter:

```
let count f =
  let inc = ref 0 in
  (fun x -> inc := !inc + 1; print_int !inc; f x);;
```

This function is polymorphic: `('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b`.

Next, let's define two more functions. A weekly polymorphic:

```
let max' = count max;;
val max' : '_a -> '_a -> '_a = <fun>
```

and a polymorphic one:

```
let max'' x = count max x;;
val max'' : 'a -> 'a -> 'a = <fun>
```

Now notice what is printed when we execute these functions:

```
max' 1 2;;  (* prints 1 *)
max' 1 2;;  (* prints 2 *)
max' 1 2;;  (* prints 3 *)
max'' 1 2;; (* prints 1 *)
max'' 1 2;; (* prints 1 *)
max'' 1 2;; (* prints 1 *)
```

So the function that we designed as weekly polymorphic has a *persistent mutable state* inside that allows to use the counter as expected, while the polymorphic function is *stateless* and is reconstructed with every call, although we wanted to have a mutable variable inside.

This is the reason for a compiler to prefer a weakly polymorphic function that can be used with any single type instead of supporting full-fledged polymorphism.

Comment: Why adding 'l' at the end of the function definition makes it strong polymorphic?

Comment: Yes, this is the value restriction. For cases like yours the classic way to get full polymorphism is "eta expansion" which is exactly what you have in the first function.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield what I don't understand is `why adding an extra parameter will make it strong`.

Comment: @JacksonTale, I expanded my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Languages in the ML family apply a purely syntactic test to see if it's safe to have full polymorphism. It's called the value restriction. One of your funs passes the test and one doesn't. The second is just an expr, the first is a lambda.

Answer (score 2):

A function with the type `'_a list list -> '_a list` is weakly polymorphic. What this means is that if you call the second one on an `int list list`, `rev_flatten` will no longer by `'_a list list -> 'a list` but `int list list -> int list`

You can read more here about the details of why here:
http://caml.inria.fr/resources/doc/faq/core.en.html

Cheers,

Scott

Answer (score 2):

This is just the ML-style value restriction. There are some good references in a previous SO answer by gasche: [What is the difference between 'a and '_l?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242677/what-is-the-difference-between-a-and-l).

Generally speaking the ML family applies a simple syntactic test to see whether it's safe to fully generalize, that is, to make a type fully polymorphic. If you generalize a case that's not safe, the program has undefined behavior (it can crash or get the wrong answer). So you need to do it only when safe.

The syntactic rule is applied because it's (relatively) easy to remember. A more complex rule was tried for a while, but it caused more harm than good (was the general conclusion). A historic description of the ML family will explain it better than I can.

One of your functions (the second one) is defined as an expression, i.e., as a function application. This is not "safe" according to the value restriction. (Remember, it's a syntactic test only.) The first is a lambda (fun x -> expr). This is "safe".

It's called the value restriction because it considers values to be safe. A function application is not a (syntactic) value. A lambda is a syntactic value. Something like `[]` is a value. Something like `ref []` is not a value.