# Enforcing a polymorphic type variable on an external

Tags: types, polymorphism, ocaml, external, ffi

The root of the problem is with this `external`:

```
external make : string -> 'a -> unit = "debug"
```

which I need to use with any kind of type:

```
let debug = make "name:space:a"

let _ = debug "log this thing"
let _ = debug 42
```

Unfortunately this results in the following error on the last line:

> This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type string

So I need to make the type parameter explicitly polymorphic, but from what I can understand this can for some reason only be done in type annotations attached to let bindings. Adding it to the external yields a syntax error. So I try:

```
let debug : 'a. 'a -> unit = make "name:space:a"
```

which of course results in the error:

> This definition has type 'a -> unit which is less general than 'a0. 'a0 -> unit

So I try another way of cheating the system, and add this right after the `external`:

```
let make : 'a. string -> 'a -> unit = make
```

which to my surprise does NOT give me a similar type error on this line, but seems to just ignore the type annotation and continues to give me the same  error on `let debug ...`.

This leaves me very confused, and with the following questions:

1. Is it really not possible to define an external with a polymorphic type?
2. Regardless of the answer to 1, why is it not possible to use explicit polymorphic type annotations with externals?
3. Why is the type annotation on `let make ...` completely ignored?

Note: I'm using BuckleScript, which is on 4.02.3. Online playground [here](https://reasonml.github.io/try/?ocaml=KYDwLsBOB2CGA2ACAtrA1sRAuRBnMkAltAOaIC0AfIgOSwXUCu0hYiAvIgEQAmwARoxJcAUPGBtUGbLVgA6PAWJkqshomasOKdMBFiJiPoLI46Cuus1tOUzFzjJgWXAAdYAY2exRBtgH1tYyFueAB7MjAAC0JcRGjlUXEAoIEQgBYAJiA).

Answer (score 4):

This is the value restriction, not a consequence of using `external`. (Previous discussion, one of many: [The value restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507448/the-value-restriction).)

Your definition of `debug` is a function application, so it can't be generalized (made polymorphic).

The solution is to do eta expansion:

```
let debug x = make "name:space:a" x
```

Now your definition of `debug` is a lambda, which can be generalized.

(Previous discussion of eta expansion: [Why does OCaml sometimes require eta expansion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763412/why-does-ocaml-sometimes-require-eta-expansion))

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand how the value restriction would apply if I *were* allowed to make it explicitly polymorphic. The function returns unit, so it would just be a black hole for opaque values of whatever type, wouldn't it? Also, while eta expansion would solve the problem from a type perspective, it would kind of defeat the purpose of having a function  return another function for reasons other than just enabling partial application.

Comment: You can't use annotation to get around the value restriction, that would be unsound in general. However, the value restriction is not exact, it is a little too restrictive. You can pretty easily find harmless cases where generalization is forbidden.