# OCAML module contains type variables that cannot be generalized

Tags: ocaml

Code:

```
  let size = 10
  let getTbl = Array.init size ~f:(fun _ -> Avltree.empty )
end
```

Error:

```
Error: The type of this module,
       sig val size : int val getTbl : ('_weak1, '_weak2) Avltree.t array end,
       contains type variables that cannot be generalized
```

How do I let the Ocaml compiler know that I plan to store both my key's and values as ints?

Have tried a few different approaches - none of which have worked.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763412/why-does-ocaml-sometimes-require-eta-expansion?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Weak type variables denote types that are not yet inferred, usually because you have defined a program variable and never used it, so the type checker has no idea what this variable contains. It is fine, in general, as the first usage of the variable will define its type. However,  since the whole type checking routine in OCaml is bounded by the scope of a compilation unit (i.e., a file), such variables should be defined before you compile your file.

Therefore, you have to either (1) use the variable, (2) constraint it to some type, e.g., `(let getTbl : (int, int) Avltree.t array) ..` in the implementation (.ml) file, or (3) in the `mli` file. You can even just create an empty `.mli` file (with the same name as you .ml file) and this will automatically hide all variables defined in your module and enable compilation.

Answer (score 1):

It might work to change `Avltree.empty` to `(Avltree.empty : (int, int) Avltree.t)`