# Why is this weakly polymorphic

Tags: ocaml

I am starting to learn OCaml and was trying to do some practices:

```
# let left x y = x;;
val left : 'a -> 'b -> 'a = <fun>

# let first = List.fold_right left;;
val first : '_a list -> '_a -> '_a = <fun>
```

Why is `first` only weakly polymorphic instead of fully polymorphic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between 'a and '\_l?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242677/what-is-the-difference-between-a-and-l)

Comment: try to search SO for "ocaml value restriction", there're plenty of good answers.

Comment: And I like this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22507665/2625442

Answer (score 1):

This is the value restriction. `first` is not a value, it's a function application.

To get a fully polymorphic version, use eta expansion:

```
# let left x y = x;;
val left : 'a -> 'b -> 'a = <fun>
# let first a b = List.fold_right left a b;;
val first : 'a list -> 'a -> 'a = <fun>
```

As @ivg points out, this is a commonly asked OCaml question.

**Update**

Here's a function application that's unsafe to generalize:

```
# let f x = ref x;;
val f : 'a -> 'a ref = <fun>
# f [];;
- : '_a list ref = {contents = []}
```

If you pretend that the result has the type `'a list ref` you can make the code go wrong (I tried it).

Here's a partial application that's unsafe to generalize:

```
# let g x = let z = ref x in fun () -> z;;
val g : 'a -> unit -> 'a ref = <fun>
# g [];;
- : unit -> '_a list ref = <fun>
```

If you pretend that the result has type `unit -> 'a list ref` you can make this code go wrong (I tried it).

Comment: Actually, can you please explain to me what is the harmness in this case if value restriction was not there, say `let first = List.fold_right left` become `val first: 'a list -> 'a -> 'a = <fun>`?

Comment: Or give an example of partial application would fail without value restriction?

Comment: or the reason value restriction is there is because of allowing imperative / ref?

Comment: Yes, the value restriction is there because of `ref`. That's why pure languages like Haskell don't have this restriction.

Comment: @Tarmil I understand why value restriction is necessary, but I can't see why partial function application would need value restriction. Can you construct a situation where partial application could break things if there is no value restriction?

Comment: A partial application is really just an application that returns a function. There's nothing particularly special about partial applications. No application (partial or not) is a value in the sense of the value restriction.