# What's the type of List.map List.map

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

The function List.map has this type:

```
# List.map;;
- : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list = <fun>
```

and can be used it in this simple way:

```
# List.map square [1;2;3;4];;
- : int list = [1; 4; 9; 16]
```

My question is:

What is the type of this function and an example of use ?

```
# let superMap = List.map List.map;;
val superMap : ('_a -> '_b) list -> ('_a list -> '_b list) list = <fun>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a function that takes a list of function :

Comment: This is a function that takes as argument a list of function : (List.map List.map) [(fun x -> x+1)];;. Having said that, I am not yet able to use it.

Comment: Check out that question and its answer for an explanation of the meaning of the underscore in type parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242677/what-is-the-difference-between-a-and-l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example :

```
let f_list =  (List.map List.map) [(fun x -> x+1);(fun x -> 2*x)];;
val f_list : (int list -> int list) list = [<fun>; <fun>]
```

So it takes a list of function as input , and return a list of functions operating on lists.

```
List.map (fun f -> f [1;2;3]) f_list;;
- : int list list = [[2; 3; 4]; [2; 4; 6]]
```

So what it does : it operates each of the simple function listed at the beginning on each of the elements on the int list.

...but what a strange function !

Answer (score 1):

This is another way in which you could determine the type:
Suppose the maps are of types (haskell notation)

```
map  :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map2 :: (c -> d) -> [c] -> [d]
```

you can hunt down the result by substituting the type variables. In the case of map map2, the substitution can be done: a unifies with (c -> d), and b unifies with the remaining [c] -> [d].
Substituting these variables in the type of map (and etching off the first argument of map (which is map2)) gets you the following type:

```
map map2 :: [c -> d] -> [[c] -> [d]]
```