# Ocaml values do not match for parameterized type in module and signature

Tags: module, polymorphism, ocaml

I'm trying to do one of the extended exercises in http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/nondet-effect.html#no-functor and replace the `int_t` type with `'a repr`. While trying to do this, I'm stuck on the following error:

```
Values do not match:
  val cons : '_a repr -> '_a list_t -> '_a list_t
is not included in
  val cons : 'a repr -> 'a list_t -> 'a list_t
```

my implementation of `cons` looks like

```
let cons: 'a repr -> 'a list_t -> 'a list_t =
  liftm2 (fun h t -> h::t)
```

which definitely has the right type. Why are these apparently identical types incompatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a minimal example helped me solve the problem!
I was able to reduce the failing case down to this:

```
module type Test = sig
  type 'a t
  val id: 'a t -> 'a t
end

module TestT: Test = struct
  type 'a t = 'a

  let id_maker () x = x
  let id: 'a t -> 'a t =
    id_maker ()
end
```

which indicates that I'm falling victim to [value restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507448/the-value-restriction).
There's a similar problem in [this other stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242677/what-is-the-difference-between-a-and-l), but I was misled by the module error message.
I fixed the problem by changing from

```
let cons: 'a repr -> 'a list_t -> 'a list_t =
  liftm2 (fun h t -> h::t)
```

to

```
let cons: 'a repr -> 'a list_t -> 'a list_t =
  fun h t -> liftm2 (fun h t -> h::t) h t
```