# Why does compiler identify two equivalent signatures with different names of generic type variables as different types?

Tags: generics, ocaml, type-inference, type-signature, type-variables

**Question**

Why are

```
val of_bindings : (key * '_a) list -> '_a t
val of_bindings : (key * 'a) list -> 'a t
```

different signatures?

**Context**

I have some Map extension implementation:

**MAPEXT.ml   :**

```
module type T = sig
    include Map.S    
    val of_bindings : (key * 'a) list -> 'a t
  end
```

**mapExt.mli  :**

```
module Make (Key : Map.OrderedType)
     : MAPEXT.T with type key = Key.t
```

**mapExt.ml   :**

```
module Make (Key : Map.OrderedType) = struct
    include Map.Make (Key)
    let of_bindings =
      let rec of_bindings acc =
        function | (k, v) :: t -> of_bindings (add k v acc) t
                 | []          -> acc in
      of_bindings empty
  end
```

Compiler gave me an error as a result of
`ocamlopt -c MAPEXT.ml mapExt.mli mapExt.ml`

> Error: The implementation mapExt.ml does not match the interface
>   mapExt.cmi:
>          ...
>         At position module Make(Key) : 
>          Values do not match:
>          **val of_bindings : (key * '_a) list -> '_a t**
>        is not included in
>          **val of_bindings : (key * 'a) list -> 'a t**
>        File "mapExt.ml"

I thought the name of generic type variable is not important, just for signalling a different type. But from what I see now they seem to have different meanings.

How to avoid this problem to compile this code?

Related: [What is the difference between 'a and '_l?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242677/what-is-the-difference-between-a-and-l)

Comment: Please read "A function obtained through partial application is not polymorphic enough" and following sections of https://ocaml.org/learn/faq.html#Typing

Answer (score 3):

This is not just a different name (you are right a name of a type variable doesn't matter). If a type variable name starts with the `'_` sequence, it is a compiler way to say that this type variable is weakly polymorphic. To put it simply, it is not polymorphic at all, and it denotes that your value is not generic. Basically, a type variable denotes, that your value has a range of types, e.g., `'a list` is a value that may belong to a range of types, e.g., `int list`, `string list`, etc. In other words, a type variable denotes an infinite range of types, i.e., it is the for all notation. The weak type variable is the opposite, as it doesn't range over many types, but only over one type, i.e., if you have a value of type `'_a list` it means that there exists a type `x` (one and only one) such that the type of your value is `x list`. It's just that the compiler doesn't know the type yet. As a matter of courtesy, the compiler gives us an extra latitude and doesn't give a type error.

The reason why a type variable is not generalized to the for all notion but sticks to the exists notation, hides in the mutability of OCaml and function application. The general rule is that if the compiler can't prove that a value computation doesn't have any observable side effects, then the value is not generalized, and all type variables remain weak. Since a value that is obtained from a partial function application is a result of an arbitrary computation, the compiler conservatively assumes that the computation may have a side effect an doesn't generalize the type. This is called the [value restriction](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/imperative-programming-1.html#side-effects-and-weak-polymorphism) and it is a feature of the OCaml type system. The usual way to deal with it is to add all the parameters so that the value is not produced by a partial application, but will become a syntactic value - a class of values that are computed (determined) during the compilation. The fancy name for this mechanism is [Eta Expansion](http://caml.inria.fr/resources/doc/faq/core.en.html#eta-expansion).